# PowerShell variable usage out of For Each loop

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am writing a PowerShell script that attempts a connection to a list of servers on port 3389. When the connection fails, the script sends an email.

The lines (variables) in question are commented out at the beginning of the script and will only work when referenced within the loop. Can you please help me understand why, when sending an email from within the loop while the $subject and $body variables are outside of the loop, the $server variable is only ever the very last server on the list?

It seems to me that when the $subject and $body reference the $server variable, it would be set to whatever $server the ForEach loop is currently working with. Maybe I'm misunderstanding  scripting rules in general?

Thanks in advance!

```
# $subject = "$server is not accepting RDP connections!"  # Why do these two lines have to be in the loop?
# $body = " Hello, `n `n This is an automatically generated message indicating that an attempt to RDP to $server has failed. Please investigate ASAP. `n `n Thank you."

$serversArray = @("host1","host2","host3")
$port = 3389
$status = ""

$emailFrom = "example@example.com"
$emailTo = "example@example.com" # To address
$relay = "smtp.example.com"
$smtp=new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($relay)

# For each loop that iterates through each server in the $serversArray array. This creates a generic socket connection and then calls it for the current server name.
# If the socket connection returns True for the connected status, the connection is closed.
# Otherwise, a failure email is sent.
ForEach ($server in $serversArray)
{
    $socket = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    $socket.Connect($server, $port)

    if ($socket.Connected) {
        $socket.Close()
        $status += "RDP port 3389 is open on $server `n"
    }
    else {
        $subject = "$server is not accepting RDP connections!"  # Everything works when this line is here, in the loop
        $body = " Hello, `n `n This is an automatically generated message indicating that an attempt to RDP to $server has failed. Please investigate ASAP. `n `n Thank you." # Everything works when this line is here, in the loop
        $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
        $status += "RDP port 3389 is NOT open on $server `n" 
    }
}

echo $status
```

Comment: I removed the extra single quote at the end of the array. The script is working fine as it is now.. just curious about the variable question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Is it possible to make $server exist outside of the "ForEach" block? I  would prefer to have $subject and $body be defined at the top. I could concatenate $server and $subject in the loop and achieve the desired result, but I don't think it would work for $body.

Comment: Mjoliner, great tip on the here-string! I will definitely make use of that. When you set $body = &$newBody, what does the ampersand do?

Comment: The & is the invocation operator.  It invokes (runs)  the script block and returns the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for moving the Subject and Body text outside the loop is to put them into a script block outside of the loop, and then invoke the script block within the loop.

```
$NewSubject = { "$server is not accepting RDP connections!" } 

 $NewBody = { @"
 Hello, 

 This is an automatically generated message indicating that an attempt to RDP to $server has failed. Please investigate ASAP.

 Thank you.
"@ }

$serversArray = @("host1","host2","host3")
$port = 3389
$status = ""

$emailFrom = "example@example.com"
$emailTo = "example@example.com" # To address
$relay = "smtp.example.com"
$smtp=new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($relay)

# For each loop that iterates through each server in the $serversArray array. This creates a    generic socket connection and then calls it for the current server name.
# If the socket connection returns True for the connected status, the connection is closed.
# Otherwise, a failure email is sent.
ForEach ($server in $serversArray)
{
    $socket = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    $socket.Connect($server, $port)

    if ($socket.Connected) {
        $socket.Close()
        $status += "RDP port 3389 is open on $server `n"
    }
    else {
        $subject = &$NewSubject
        $body = &$NewBody
        $smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
        $status += "RDP port 3389 is NOT open on $server `n" 
    }
}

echo $status
```

For multi-line text like email bodies, the here-string can make your code much easier to read by letting you enter the text with literal newlines instead of having to use escaped control characters.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
$serversArray = @("one", "two", "three")
$serversArray
ForEach ($server in $serversArray) {
  echo $server
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
one
two
three

one
two
three
```

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Delete the extraneous "," in your array definition

2) "divide and conqueor": test individual parts of your script, then put them all together.

ALSO:

3) Yes, $server exists only inside your "ForEach" block

4) Yes, you can define $subject and $body at the top.  You can't use $server yet, but you can easily concatenate the $server string with your $subject string at the point where you actually use it (inside the loop).

'Hope that helps...